# React native bundle command hangs at copying assets

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I am trying to run a react-native bundle for Android using react native cli. It hangs after trying to copy assets to the "res" folder. I am running it on Windows 10.

Here is the console output:

```
C:\..\ReactNative>react-native bundle --platform android --dev true --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ".\android
\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle" --assets-dest ".\android\src\main\res\"

[01/14/2017, 08:13:44] <START> Initializing Packager
[01/14/2017, 08:13:47] <START> Building Haste Map
[01/14/2017, 08:13:48] <END>   Building Haste Map (810ms)
[01/14/2017, 08:13:48] <END>   Initializing Packager (4287ms)
[01/14/2017, 08:13:48] <START> Transforming files
[01/14/2017, 08:14:02] <END>   Transforming files (14205ms)
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: .\android\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Copying 5 asset files
```

Based on what I see in the [source file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/bundle/saveAssets.js), it should resolve a promise after completing the step. It worked previously, but then out of a sudden stopped working.

Does anyone have any suggestions what could be an issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was simple - I had an incorrect path to the destination folder. In order to solve the problem I added logging to the bundle.js file in the react native CLI and just watched the console output to tell me what was wrong.

Comment: Could you please share how you added logging to the bundle.js? Thanks

Comment: I just went into node_modules/react-native folder, modified the react native cli javascript code, added logging there and rerun the whole thing.